# redirect string to different url in nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite

I want to redirect a string to different URL in nginx.

This what my vhost looks like and is working fine.

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name secure.example.com;
  root /opt/tomcat/webapps/test/;
  rewrite ^/Crest(.*)$ /$1;
  location / {
    proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8080/Crest;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

}
```

Now I just want to redirect `http://secure.example.com/Crest?page=login to http://example.com` or `/Crest?page=login to http://example.com`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : I have tried lot of things, but deleted once which were not working. Let me specify few of them I used MAP and the called $new in location as rewrite ^ $new redirect; I also used SCHEME, but that didn't work for me.      rewrite ^/Crest?page=login $scheme://example.com permanent;
    if ( $query_string ~  /Crest?page=login ) {
   rewrite ^ http://example.com/? permanent;
}

Comment: @MichaelHampton where am I making mistake, please let me know.

Comment: I think the problem with both of your attempts is that you are trying to compare `$query_string` with the full URI of the document. `$query_string` contains only the part after `?` in the URI, so the comparison doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve the goal you want in nginx. You have to make the redirection inside your application, that is, add the code to `page=login` part of the app.

Comment: Its working fine, I just want ?page=login to be executed and then redirected to http://example.com. Currently what is happening is that the page is not getting logged out and it is directly redirecting to the url.

Comment: Ah, that is completely different then.. I edited my answer. You need to ensure that the code in `page=login` to make the redirect to `example.com`. nginx cannot do that.